# Can I rationalize the denominator of $\frac{1}{\pi}$?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Can I rationalize the denominator of $\frac{1}{\pi}$?

Comment: So are you asking whether $\pi$ is rational? It's not.

Comment: No. Pi is transcendental and no polynomial or rational function of Pi with rational coefficients can yield a rational.

Comment: @MattiP.: I think the OP wants to mimic $1/\sqrt2\to\sqrt2/2$.

Comment: $1/\pi$ is transcendental number.

Comment: Well, there's $\frac{1/\pi}1$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot.

This is a consequence of the fact that $\pi$ is transcendental. This implies that there are no algebraic manipulations with rational numbers we can do (besides multiplying by $0$, which is obviously not allowed) which will yield a rational number in the denominator.

The reason we can rationalize the denominator in e.g. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is that $\sqrt{2}$ is algebraic (as opposed to $\pi$, which is transcendental).